# Issue with the Object Type in Angular Component.ts Module

Tags: angular, callback, web-frontend

I just started with the newest Angular Version. The variable **contacts** is an array.

Now I 've got an error with the methods:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe(
      contacts => 
      {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        console.log(this.contacts);
      }
      );
```

The message shows:

> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Contact[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2696)

I tried many times to fix that problems but didn't find the right solution.

The whole code is posted here:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ContactService} from '../contact.service'
import {Contact} from '../contact';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.scss'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts: Contact[];
  contact: Contact;
  first_name:string;
  last_name:string;
  phone: string;
  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }


 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe(
      contacts => 
      {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        console.log(this.contacts);
      }
      );

    }
}
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

I added the service code module here:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
//import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Contact} from './contact';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  //retrieving ContactService
  getContacts()
  {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3002/api/contacts');
   
  }
  //add contact method
  addContact(newContact) {
    var headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3002/api/contact', newContact, {headers:headers})
     
      
  }

  //delete methods
deleteContact(id)
{
  return this.http.delete('http://localhost:3002/api/contact'+ id);
}

}
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz so i can help you better https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Change only the declaration of contacts: Contact[]; as contacts:any = {} or contacts:any = []

Comment: You shouldn't be changing `Object` to `any`. You're replacing a lesser evil with a greater evil. Refactor `getContacts()` to return `Contact[]` instead.

Comment: I think there is problem in what you api Calls return please also post the service code..!!

Comment: Does contactService.getContacts() return a observable<array>? I think that may be your issue

Comment: Thanks for your help. @BrendanB right, the contactService.getContacts() return an observable<array>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

1. Change `contacts` member property declaration.
2. Change response type on subscription like given in answer

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ContactService} from '../contact.service'
import {Contact} from '../contact';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.scss'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {
  contacts: Array<Contact> = []; // change like this
  contact: Contact;
  first_name:string;
  last_name:string;
  phone: string;
  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }


 

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe(
      (contacts: any) => // set response type to any
      {
        this.contacts = contacts;
        console.log(this.contacts);
      }
      );

    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Santosh this was helpful and you fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

A proper way would be to type the return of your service function:

```
  getContacts(): Observable<Contact[]> {
     return this.http.get('http://localhost:3002/api/contacts');
  }
```

Going a bit further, the get method of the HttpClient is generically typed, so you can suggest the return type this way:

```
this.http.get<Contact[]>(url);
```

You can then type your declaration in the calling component:

```
 this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe(
  (contacts: Contact[]) => 
  {
    this.contacts = contacts;
    console.log(this.contacts);
  }
  );

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help.  I will try this out for sure. Very useful tips.

Comment: I must mention that is the recommended way though, the use of **any** typing is the last thing you want to do usually ;)